# How to store string '2020-09-1015:45:59+10:00' into date column

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime

In my Oracle db I have a date column with datatype as Date.
I want to store input string value- '2020-09-1015:45:59+10:00' into my date column. I don't want to ignore timezone value as well.

Please advise query/clause that will serve this.

Thank you

Comment: dates are stored as packets without format. If you want to store that format, you can't use date

Comment: you can use `timestamp with time zone` as data type in this case, but again the data is not stored that way, it is presented in that way

Comment: The `date` datatype does not contain timezone information, so you'll either need a second column to hold the timezone or offset, or else change the column to `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: Hi @Roberto Hernandez
Can you please elaborate with Syntax?
I was trying the below code but it didn't work-

declare
x varchar2(50);
start_datetime__w  timestamp(3) with time zone;
timezone_name__w   varchar2(500);
Begin
x:='2020-09-10T15:45:59+10:00';
timezone_name__w:= nvl(pkg_config.get_value('timezone_name',pkg_dc.get_active_dc),'Australia/Brisbane');
start_datetime__w := to_timestamp_tz(x||' '||timezone_name__w,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZR');
dbms_output.put_line(start_datetime__w);
end;
/

Comment: `to_timestamp_tz('2020-09-1015:45:59+10:00','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')` will do it, but casting to `date` loses the timezone offset. What date value do you want to store?

Answer (score 1):

A `DATE` column does not have a time zone; so, if you want to store the value `2020-09-1015:45:59+10:00` in a `DATE` column then the time zone cannot be stored so to have consistent values you'll need to convert the value to a known time zone (typically this is UTC+0):

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table ( your_date_column )
VALUES (
  CAST(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
      '2020-09-10 15:45:59+10:00',
      'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
    ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
    AS DATE
  )
)
```

Which would store the value in the UTC time zone:

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

> ```
> | YOUR_DATE_COLUMN    |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-09-10T05:45:59 |
> ```

If you want to store the `TIME ZONE` data as well then you cannot use a `DATE` column and should use a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type instead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_date_column TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE )
```

and you could insert like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table ( your_date_column )
VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    '2020-09-10 15:45:59+10:00',
    'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
  )
)
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | YOUR_DATE_COLUMN                    |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 2020-09-10T15:45:59.000000000+10:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5909c17fecfa3f92ce445d8bebd8c975)*

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: if you want to store the timezone, then you need datatype `timestamp with time zone`.

```
create table t (ts timestamp with time_zone);
```

If you want to provide a string directly, one option is to change the nls format of this datatype to your format:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp__tz_format = 'yyyy-mm-ddhh24:mi:ss tzr';
```

Then you can pass the string directly for `insert`, and rely on Oracle's implicit conversion to turn it to a timestamp:

```
insert into t values('2020-09-1015:45:59+10:00');
```

Accordingly, when you `select` that column, you get a string in the configured format:

```
select * from t;
```

```
| TS                        |
| :------------------------ |
| 2020-09-1015:45:59 +10:00 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f87f12618f9e1d7d69f0da01574a341d)**